# Differential form taking values in a vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $\pi: P \rightarrow M$ be a $G$-principal bundle. Define $\Omega^k_{\text{hor}}(P, \mathfrak{g})^{\text{Ad}}$ to be the set of $k$-forms $\omega$ taking values in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ associated to $G$ such that it is horizontal and of type Ad, i.e. for all $p \in P$:

1. $\omega_p(X_1, \ldots, X)k = 0$  whenever at least one of the vectors $X_i \in T_pP$ is vertical.
2. $r^*_g \omega = \text{Ad}_{g^{-1}} \circ \omega$ for all $g \in G$.

I am studying the following theorem found in Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory*

> The vector space $\Omega^k_{\text{hor}}(P, \mathfrak{g})^{\text{Ad}}$ is canonically isomorphic to the vector space $\Omega^k(M, \text{Ad}(P))$.

Here Ad$(P)$ is the adjoint bundle associated to $P$.

I have a simple question about this theorem. Here we are looking at vector-valued forms, however Ad$(P)$ is a vector bundle and not just a vector space. Thus at each point in $M$ the output of any such form $\omega$ takes values in the vector bundle Ad$(P)$.

How is this a vector valued form? Are we implicitly taking the output to be in the fiber in Ad$(P)$ over some point in $M$ (i.e. a vector space isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$)? If so, why not just write $\Omega^k(M, \mathfrak{g})$? What is the difference between $\Omega^k(M, \text{Ad}(P))$ and $\Omega^k(M, \mathfrak{g})$? Furthermore, if this is the case, how does this form retain any information about the adjoint representation as opposed to just $\mathfrak{g}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write $\Omega^k(M,\mathfrak{g})$ instead of $\Omega^k(M,\text{Ad}(P))$? Because they are not the same. Try to come up with an example where this is the case (of course, $G$ should be non-abelian, otherwise they are the same for sure!). For example, work out the case of the $\text{SU}(2)$ Hopf fibration.

And why are sections of $\Omega^k(M,\text{Ad}(P))$ still vector-valued $k$-forms? Well, $\text{Ad}(P)$ is locally trivial and so these $k$-forms obey similar rules to ordinary differential forms. However, they transform differently under coordinate changes than elements of $\Omega^k(M,V)$ with $V$ a vector space. And this is important to make the isomorphism $\Omega^k(M,\text{Ad}(P))\cong \Omega^k_\text{hor}(P,\mathfrak{g})^\text{Ad}$ work out.

Comment: I would not use the phrase “vector-valued differential form” for a differential form with values in a vector bundle. To me, the former connotes values in a fixed vector space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Given that the philosophy of differential geometry is, often times, to do "parameterised linear algebra", I think it is more natural to call all differential forms with values in a vector bundle "vector valued differential forms".  This is because they all share the same local description. The author of the wikipedia article on vector-valued differential forms shares this sentiment, but of course every individual can decide what terminology to use for themselves.

Comment: @QuaereVerum So we call $\Omega^k(M,\text{Ad}(P))$ a vector-valued $k$-form because it locally looks like and transforms like a vector but otherwise is not really vector valued? I'm still a little confused on this point, do you mind elaborating on it? I am guessing that $\Omega^k(M,\mathfrak{g})$ and $\Omega^k(M,\text{Ad}(P))$ are not the same whenever Ad$(P)$ is not the trivial bundle.

Comment: @CBBAM (Part 1) I would rather say that $M\times\mathfrak{g}$ and $\text{Ad}(P)$ aren't necessarily the same. It is possible for $P$ to be non-trivial over $M$, while $\text{Ad}(P)$ is trivial (e.g. when $G$ is abelian). Regarding the terminology: we call it a vector valued form because, if you trivialise $\text{Ad}(P)$ over $U\subseteq M$, then sections of $\text{Ad}(P)|_U\cong U\times\mathfrak{g}$ are "ordinary" vector valued differential forms, i.e. elements of $\Omega^k(U)\otimes\mathfrak{g}$. However, sections of $\text{Ad}(P)$ obey different transformation rules.

Comment: @CBBAM (Part 2) In concrete terms, look at $\omega\in \Omega^k(M,\text{Ad}(P))$ pointwise, i.e. take $x\in M$. Then $\omega_x:\wedge^k T_xM\to\mathfrak{g}$ is a $k$-form (in the linear algebra sense) on $T_xM$ with values in $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\omega_x\in (\wedge^kT_x^*M)\otimes\mathfrak{g}$. So pointwise, vector bundle valued differential forms are indistinguishable from differential forms of the kind $\Omega^k(M)\otimes V$. But again, in the global picture, they obey different transformation rules (they come from a different vector bundle). The terminology "vector valued" still applies.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you for the very helpful comments! I see the difference now.